# Flut UI Icons On switches are doubling up

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

using

```
<div class="switch switch-square"
   data-on-label="<i class='fui-check'></i>"
   data-off-label="<i class='fui-cross'></i>">
      <input type="checkbox" />
</div>
```

it generates:

```
<span class="switch-left">
      <i class="fui-check">
         <span style="font-family: 'Flat-UI-Icons'"></span></i></span>
```

Which creates this problem that is shown[image: here]
And it wont display in Chrome and I have no idea why.

Comment: Can you provide a demo on jsfiddle?

Comment: That is a little difficult considering there are so many files involved

Comment: Im confused why it is generating the icon twice as well as not displaying in Chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue, was including `IE-7` javascript files which was giving it double icons, still doesn't answer why it wont work in chrome.